# [UICollectionViewCell imageCell]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios6, selector, uicollectionviewcell

I read ALL questions with this tittle. FavoritosViewController.m I have:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
favcolCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"fav" forIndexPath:indexPath];
[[cell imageCell]setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[arrayimages objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]]];
return cell;
}
```

on favcolCell.h I have:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageCell;
```

on favcolCell.m I have:

```
    @synthesize imageCell;
```

(...)

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [imageCell release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

What I'm missing?

EDIT:

Solution: Do the right class registration.

Comment: Do you know what the "unrecognized selector" message means?  It means that the named class does not have a "selector" (method) of that name.  Usually this is because you have the wrong object type in a variable.

Comment: I know what it means, I have the right classes on the storyboard, I checked it many times. Do you have any suggest?

Comment: Well, UICollectionViewCell does not have a method called "imageCell".

Comment: So.. Why if I try: `cell.imageCell.image=[[UIImage alloc]init];` it give me the same error?

Comment: Did you read the spec:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:  (Particularly the part about registering your class?)

Comment: Are you talking about this: `[self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"fav"];` I have it too..

Comment: So you didn't register favcolCell?

Comment: (How is dequeueReusableCell.. supposed to know it should return a favcolCell??)

Comment: What's your point? it returns a UICollectionReusableView object. favcolCell is a UICollectionViewCell.

Comment: No, it's returning a UICollectionViewCell, as shown by the error message.  favcolCell is a SUBCLASS of the first class and is NOT being returned.  If it were (and you somehow got the error message) it would name favcolCell.

Comment: (And, by the way, you should always use initial upper case for class names.  Avoids confusion.)

Comment: I still not understand your point, I saw five tutorials and all did the same thing.. creating the dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier instace and returning it. (this only exists since the iOS6) Do you have a solution for me?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CollectionView-Simple/Listings/CollectionView_ViewController_m.html look to this example please.

Comment: Register the right class.  You're not getting a favcolCell from that call.

Comment: @FabioCardoso If you have solved your problem, add the solution as an answer and mark it as accepted so other users can see this is not an open question.

Comment: @HotLicks If you have a solution to a question please post it as an answer, not in the comments.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I missed this:

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[FavoritosRestViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"fav"];
```

on the `ViewDidLoad` Method. I registered the wrong class. Thanks to user HotLicks.

Answer (score 0):

For me this is the solutions..

I have taken one collection view and imageView inside cell. But I forgot to set tag in the interface(storyboard) file.

Storyboard-> collection view->image view->property inspector->set tag here.

I hope it helps someone.